# Parse CSV in transformation

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have an SSH step that executes a command which outputs CSV. This CSV should be parsed for further processing, however in Spoon I only found steps for parsing CSV data in files. How can I parse the `stdOut` field of the SSH step as CSV without writing it to a file first?

Comment: Other than reimplementing CSV functionality with the Split Fields or Row Normaliser steps, I don't see a way with the built-in steps. Can I ask for the reason behind avoiding a buffer file? There is a decrease in performance when buffering into a file, however the output of a SSH step has to be parsed in its entirety before the next step can continue, so it might be that this defeats any chunking PDI does, which in turn decreased performance anyway. But that depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MAC / Linux or windows 10 WSL try using AWK before parsing it via Kettle.

It can parse CSV very easily.

Example : Code like this will parse the csv filter the rows and extract necessary columns which are needed.

```
$ awk -F ',' '{if($4 == "Online" && $5 =="L") {print $1,$2,$4}}' sales_100.csv
```

More info : 
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/use-awk-to-save-time-and-money-in-data-science-eb4ea0b7523f